# Does dkms in Ubuntu 18.04 and later sign modules/drivers automatically?

Tags: drivers, secure-boot, displaylink

According to [DisplayLink website](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181617):

> Since Ubuntu 18.04 signing modules is handled automatically by dkms
> package, remember to reboot to finalize

However when secure boot was enabled in order for the drivers to work I followed [the following instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules) and signed the module myself.

I'm trying to understand if dkms handles signing automatically? If so how can you tell or are there additional steps needed (since it didn't work without signing)?

Answer (score 0):

This is described in detail in the article
[Automatic Signing of DKMS-Generated Kernel Modules for Secure Boot (Nvidia Driver on CentOS 8 as Example)](https://gist.github.com/lijikun/22be09ec9b178e745758a29c7a147cc9).

For DKMS to automatically sign generated modules, it must be configured
to do so for each module.

- Prequisites: openssl, mokutil and dkms; kernel source.
- Generate and import a Machine Owner Key (MOK) for signing the kernel module
- Configure DKMS.

The exact steps are described in the above article.

A summary of the steps may be found in the post
[Signing dkms module automatically enabled in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240517/signing-dkms-module-automatically-enabled-in-ubuntu-20-04).

Useful code may be found in the archived Github article
[dkms-module-signing.md](https://web.archive.org/web/20191206074759/https://gist.github.com/dop3j0e/2a9e2dddca982c4f679552fc1ebb18df).